# Java - Cannot see Process output live

Tags: java, process, stream

I have a Java program with the following code. I execute an external C program (on my Windows 7 machine) which prints a single character, P or R, every second, to the standard error stream. However, the result of this output, (the execution of `pressed()` and `released()`, only shows up when the process is terminated (while I need it live). So if I terminate the process after a while it works, but doesn't if the program is left open (as it is now and as it needs to be). What might be wrong?

```
    try {
        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("remotek.exe");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                p.destroy();
            }
        });
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
        while (true) {
            int c = r.read();
            if (c == 'P') {
                pressed();
            }
            if (c == 'R') {
                released();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I should add that the program stops at `r.read()` as if there was nothing to read yet. A flushing problem?

Comment: It looks like you are only reading the error stream, not the output stream.